# Hide entire div with conditional javascript (missing avatar image)

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently using CSS to hide a class if the image "src" is using a blank avatar image.

However, I also need to create a condition that will hide the entire div (class="s-lib-featured-profile-container") when the above is true.

I am currently implementing the below without success.

```
<style>
.s-lib-featured-profile-image [src="//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg"] {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 if( $('.s-lib-featured-profile-image img[src="https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg"]').length ) {
    console.log('hiding...');
    $('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

```
<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container">
        <a href="/prf.php?account_id=127256">
            <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
                <img src="https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg" alt="">
            </div> 
        </a>
</div>
```

Ultimately, I just need to hide the `<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container">` if the image src within is: `<img src="https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg">`

Any help for this novice would be appreciated!

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to check whether or not a file exists and based on that hide / show an element

Comment: That's correct Joeri. Basically hide the ```<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container">``` if someone has not uploaded a profile image (meaning the /profile.jpg image would be seen in its place).

Comment: you could try to hide it by default and use onload on the image, something like `<img src="myimg.png" onload="show();" />`, this will make sure it only shows when the image can be loaded

Answer (score 1):

Use the element's onload event:

```
<img onload="$(this).parents('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').hide()" ...>
```

or:

```
$('.s-lib-featured-profile-container img').load(function() {
   $(this).parents('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').hide();
});
```

Comment: This does do the trick when I enter into the img line via the console inspect. However, I am adding in custom CSS/JS to an existing system and cannot make those line by line changes. How would I apply this to CSS/JS?

Comment: Updated the answer to include "catch-all" handler.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried...

```
$('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').css("display", "none");
```

it's not as short as .hide(), but I've had problems getting .hide() to work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

Pulling the src from the img then checking the src with the url given. If url is given then hide the div.

working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/scp1zfva/

```
$(() => {

  const src = $('img').attr('src');
  if (src === 'https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg'){
    $('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').hide();
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var img_src = $('.s-lib-featured-profile-container  img').attr('src');
if( img_src == "https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg" ) {
  $('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try various approaches, the easiest of them is using jQuery, a different one could be using AJAX and maybe you can do something with CSS parent selectors.

an example of a jQuery could be the following (heavily based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55462250/9208510) answer by @Diodeus - James MacFarlane)

```
<img src="myfile.png" onload="$(this).parents('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').show()" />
```

or

```
<img src="myfile.png" onerror="$(this).parents('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').hide()" />
```

A different approach could be by using AJAX, which could look something like this:

```
function check_availability(url, id) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          //if 200 response show the div
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
          //if no 200 response hide the div
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xhttp.send();
  }
```

I hope this can help you out